# Why can't we say that "Horses are a useful animal." treats horses as a class or set of objects?

Tags: american-english, british-english

> （1）Computers are **important research tools**.
>
> （2）Computers are **an important research tool**.

We can say that the first sentence treats computers as discrete objects.

The second  sentence treats computers as a class or set of objects.

> （3）Horses are **useful animals**.
>
> （4）Horses are **a useful animal**.

We can say that the third sentence treats horses as discrete objects.

Why can't we say the fourth sentence treats horses as a class or set of objects?

Comment: To refer to horses generically, as a class, we might say "**the horse** is a useful animal"

Comment: What a good question! I feel it has something to do with a perception that a horse is a horse by virtue of having a horsey essence, of which there is only one, whereas a computer is a computer by virtue of what it can do, and doesn't really have an essence at all - certainly not one that is shared by all the others and thus defines what it is to be a computer. Not that I'd want to try to defend that perception philosophically, but language is based on an instinctive categorisation of things that doesn't / isn't supposed to hold up to rational scrutiny.

Comment: @Minty I think the difference is that in the first sentence the computers are treated as a single tool whereas in the  second sentence the horses are referred to as 'animals'. If the first one said "Computers are important _machines_ for research"  then 'machines' has to be plural. If, on the other hand, the second sentence said "Horses are a useful _resource_" then the group noun can be singular. A computer is one machine and a horse is one animal but computers in general can be thought of as a single tool and horses in general can be thought of as a single resource. Compare like with like.

Comment: @BoldBen The question does compare like with like - it asks how come we can say *computers are an important research tool* but not *horses are a useful animal*, when these sentences seem to be the same grammatically / syntactically (doesn't it?) I'm not sure how come, but am not seeing a difference in terms of syntax or grammar, which is why I was suggesting a semantic explanation.

Comment: BTW I don't really see how all computers can be seen as a single tool, and if they can, you'd think that by the same token, horses could be seen as a single animal - that's what the OP was getting at with the reference to a class or set of objects, I think.

Comment: I see no difference at all between the examples in terms of construction. You could just as easily say *horses are important research tools* or *computers are a useful thing*. I believe you're confusing the specific words with the syntax.

Comment: You asked "Why can't we say that 'Horses are a useful animal.' ”  But *who* has said that one cannot use that expression? To me, your Q. is based on a false premise.  Please provide some evidence that the quoted sentence is not acceptable.

Comment: @Minty The difference is that each computer is, regardless of its use, a single machine. Similarly each horse is, regardless of its state of domestication or wildness, a single animal. When computers are regarded en mass as a tool the word 'tool' is a noun covering all computers. They cannot, even if connected, be considered a single machine. Similarly when horses are spoken of as a resource the word 'resource'  is a noun covering all horses. But the horses cannot be considered a single animal any more than the computers can be considered a single machine.

Comment: @BoldBen Thank you for answering.So the conclusion is that "a tool" can be considered "a class of things" , but "an animal" can't , isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think sentence #4 **does** treat *horses* as the class of all horses, and that's exactly the problem with it.

It is possible for a class of objects to be a *tool*, if those objects collectively form a resource that is useful for accomplishing some task.

But it is not possible for a class of objects to be an *animal*, which is by definition a single living being.  So sentence #4 is not grammatically wrong, it's simply nonsensical.

There is nothing inherently wrong with using *horses* as singular to refer to the class of all horses, so long as you use it in a context where that makes sense.  You could certainly say something like:

> Horses were an important method of transportation in the 19th century.

Comment: I agree, see my comments on the question.

Comment: How do I know which words can be considered " a class of objects"

Comment: @ChaiMinChun In my opinion it is a matter of whether the word is inherent to the nature of a single member of the class or not. One horse is one animal, one computer is one machine, however many horses can be one resource and many computers can be one tool. Therefore 'resource ' and 'tool' can be classes but 'animal' and 'machine' cannot.